# In N+1 position display the div cards in angular 6

Tags: angular

when I click on card clicked card and previous card is visible and others are invisible, in invisible place another div cards should be replaced. how can I do it?

In app.component.html  I am having 2 div  oninit i will call 1st div and then by click I have to replace the invisible place with 2nd div.how to do it?

app.component.html

```
1st div
<div class="row ">
   <div class=" col-md-3" *ngFor="let x of list; let i = index " style="padding:15px;">
    <div class="card ">
     <div class="card-body " *ngIf ="!x.visible">
       <img src="{{x.productImage}}" class=" rounded" (click)="display(i)" >
       <div>{{x.product_name}}</div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

/*2nd div*/

<div class="row ">
  <div class=" col-md-3" *ngFor="let y of similar; let i = index " style="padding:15px;">
   <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-body " >
     <img src="{{y.productImage}}" class=" rounded"  >
     <div>{{y.product_name}}</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
list:object;
similar:object;
ngOninit{
  this.data.getList().subscribe(data => {
  this.list  = data;
});
display(indexNumber){
this.data.getSimilar().subscribe(data => {
  this.similar  = data;
});
for(var i=indexNumber; i< this.list.length; i++){
  if (i==indexNumber || i==indexNumber-1){
    this.list[i].visible=false;
  }
  else{
    this.list[i].visible=true;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more descriptive, and elaborate on what you want to achieve, and on what the problem is with your code.

Comment: Edited the Question summary

Comment: try *ngIf or *ngSwitch

Comment: how to apply *ngSwitch?